# How to properly use componentWillUnmount() in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From the official tutorial:

> `componentWillUnmount()` is invoked immediately before a component is unmounted and destroyed. Perform any necessary cleanup in this method, such as invalidating timers, canceling network requests, or cleaning up any DOM elements that were created in `componentDidMount`

I understood "invalidating timers". `fetch` can be aborted with `AbortController`. But I don't understand "cleaning up any DOM elements that were created in `componentDidMount`", can I see examples for that case?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If the network request sending library supports aborting the ongoing network request call, you can definitely call that in `componentWillUnmount` method.

However in relation to cleaning up of `DOM` elements is of concern. I will give a couple of examples, based on my current experience.

**First one is -**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class SideMenu extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
              };
        this.openMenu = this.openMenu.bind(this);
        this.closeMenu = this.closeMenu.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener("click", this.closeMenu);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener("click", this.closeMenu);
    }

    openMenu() {
    }

    closeMenu() {
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                    <a
                        href      = "javascript:void(0)"
                        className = "closebtn"
                        onClick   = {this.closeMenu}
                    >
                        ×
                    </a>
                  <div>
                     Some other structure
                  </div>
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here I am removing the click event listener which I added when the component mounted.

**Second one is -**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import d3Chart from './d3charts';


export default class Chart extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
            data: React.PropTypes.array,
            domain: React.PropTypes.object
    };

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

    }

    componentDidMount(){
        let el = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this);
        d3Chart.create(el, {
            width: '100%',
            height: '300px'
        }, this.getChartState());
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        let el = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this);
        d3Chart.update(el, this.getChartState());
    }

    getChartState() {
        return {
            data: this.props.data,
            domain: this.props.domain
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        let el = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this);
        d3Chart.destroy(el);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Chart">
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to integrate `d3.js` with react into `componentWillUnmount`; I am removing the chart element from the DOM.

Apart from that I have used `componentWillUnmount` for cleaning up bootstrap modals after opening.

I am sure there are tons of other use cases out there, but these are the cases where I have used `componentWillUnMount`. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 9):

In this simple example (example taken from React Docs) I am using it for clearing interval of a Clock component.
For example in your page you have 2 tabs, one of them is showing `User Info` and second tab is `User Schedule` which shows a live clock over there. Once you switch to `User Schedule` tab, `componentDidMount` will be called to set the timer. And once you switch back to `User Info`, there is no need to keep this interval hook and you can write your unbind/unsubscribe logic in `componentWillUnmount` event.

```
import React from "react";
export default class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log("Clock", "constructor");
    super(props);   
    this.state = {
      date: new Date()
    };
  }
  tick() {   
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }
  // These methods are called "lifecycle hooks".
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Clock", "componentDidMount");
    this.timerID = setInterval(() => {
      this.tick();
    }, 1000);
  }
  // These methods are called "lifecycle hooks".
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("Clock", "componentWillUnmount");
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }
  render() {
    return (        
        <div>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When creating `Components` with React, not every library integrates well with it's philosophy of wanting to manage the DOM.

An example of this would be using a graphing library like [c3](http://c3js.org/). `c3` expects to be given a DOM node and will create / manage it's own markup away from React. In this case you should manage cleaning up any elements created by this library when your component is removed from the DOM.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import c3 from 'c3';

export default class Graph extends Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    this._initGraph();
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.graph = this.graph.destroy();
  }

  _initGraph () {
    this.graph = c3.generate({
      bindto: this.refs.graph
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="graph">
        <div className="graph__graph" ref="graph"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here React creates a single `div` as a placeholder for `c3` to add it's content. This process is kicked off in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook, and cleaned up again in `componentWillUnmount`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is as follows:

```
import React from "react"
export default class App extends React.Component {

  isMounted = false

  componentDidMount(){
    this.isMounted = true
    if (this.isMounted){
      this.setState({'anyState': anyState})  //call setState if component isMounted
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    this.isMounted = false
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: In componentDidMount, if you are setting `isMounted` as true then what's the point of having if condition?